# Emacs Windows spellcheck - aspell or hunspell

Tags: windows, emacs, installation, aspell, hunspell

I use emacs 23.1.50 version on Windows XP operation system. I could not setup hunspell or aspell as part of emacs with the example provided by the emacs wiki. Anyone has working confiugration for windows xp and please help me out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use aspell for spellchecking with emacs on Windows. Looking at my `.emacs` file I can see these configuration variables.

```
(custom-set-variables
    '(ispell-dictionary "british")
    '(ispell-program-name "H:\\bin\\aspell\\bin\\aspell.exe"))
```

I installed aspell with the installation wizard. `M-S-$` `ispell-buffer` `flyspell-mode` and the like all work correctly for me.

Comment: I could not make hunspell to work at any way. Now Setup with aspell and it works well.

Comment: I'll vote the answer up if You provide info how to use two dictionaries at the same time. :)

Answer (score 2):

aspell can be easily installed on windows using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). In the cygwin setup, search for aspell in the search bar and select it for installation. Remember to also select the dictionary you want to install (for the english language - aspell-en). Add the cygwin/bin directory to the load-path in emacs, so that emacs can find the executable when it needs it. Finally, add the following line to your .emacs file:

```
(setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell")
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. Only, to get it to work, I had to add the cygwin bin dir to the exec-path instead of the load-path.

Answer (score 1):

See http://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs.html

It explains why aspell is better for programmers.