# Enabling flyspell mode on emacs/w32?

Tags: emacs, flyspell

I need to install/run flyspell mode on emacs/w32.

I installed ispell for windows from [this site](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~dvanness/ispell.htm), and then I followed the procedure written in [here](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/flyspell/flyspell.html).

1. I downloaded the flyspell-1.7a.el to rename it as flyspell.el, and copied it to the load-path directory.
2. I modified the .emacs

```
;;; http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/flyspell/flyspell.html
;;; flyspell mode
  (require 'flyspell)
  (autoload 'flyspell-mode "flyspell" "On-the-fly spelling checker." t)
  (autoload 'flyspell-delay-command "flyspell" "Delay on command." t) (autoload 'tex-mode-flyspell-verify "flyspell" "" t) 
)
```

But, when I run emacs with flymode, I got the following error.

```
(error "Autoloading failed to define function turn-on-flyspell")
```

What might be wrong?

### SOLUTION with ISPELL

It was ispell for win32's problem, one should use the one that works with emacs/win32 as is explained in [the book of emacs](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/oreilly/LearningGnuEmacs/0596006489/gnu3-CHP-13-SECT-3.html).

1. Download ispell.zip from one of the [site](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/ispell.zip.352502.0.0.html).
2. Copy the ispell.exe to the PATH directory, and copy the English dictionary to the home directory.

### SOLUTION with ASPELL

[vedang](https://superuser.com/questions/193432/ispell-for-windows-7-for-flyspell-mode/193546#193546) gave a better answer with aspell [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012361/emacs-windows-spell-check-aspell-or-hunspell/2012470#2012470).

It has windows installer, dictionary install in [here](http://aspell.net/win32/). And adding the following line in .emacs works fine with me.

```
(custom-set-variables
    '(ispell-dictionary "british")
    '(ispell-program-name "H:\\bin\\aspell\\bin\\aspell.exe"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes little sense to both `require` flyspell (which will load the library), and then also declare `autoload`s for two of its functions (the purpose of which is to *avoid* loading the library in advance of those functions being called.

I don't know if this is *causing* the error (possibly the subsequent autoloads clobber the real definitions?), but there's definitely no need for both.

In fact, on Emacs 23.2.1 (if not much earlier), flyspell.el declares its own autoloads (as do all built-in libraries, I believe), so you really shouldn't have to do any of that at all if you are running a sufficiently up to date version. Which version of Emacs are we talking about?

edit: in fact `flyspell-delay-command` is not autoloaded by default in 23.2.1, so you might want to retain that line if you decide to remove the require.

Comment: I found that it's the problem that my ispell.exe doesn't work. I'm trying to find a working ispell.exe on Windows 7, but with no luck so far.

Comment: Downloaded ispell.zip, unzip it to c:\windows which is in my path and also unziped it to .emacs.d folder. Still when I start emacs in windows after C-x C-r recent files come up. When I open my todo.org file, I get Error enabling Flyspell mode: (searching for program  no such file or directory ispell.

Comment: @Stryker: The `exec-path` variable in Emacs is the list of directories in which Emacs will look for executables.

Comment: @phils: How can I run exec-path (if that is a command in emacs). Tried M-x exec-path, I get nothing. Perhaps I should not be trying it this way?

Comment: @Stryker: It's a variable, so use `C-h v exec-path` to inspect it.